# Draw curves to make arrows in the Codename One GlassPane

Tags: codenameone

In a CodenameOne App, I need to draw curved arrows in the GlassPane. The use of the GlassPane is not mandatory, however I've already used some layers in the ContentPane and some layers in the LayeredPane, so I suppose that the GlassPane is the best option to be sure that the arrows are "over" the app.

The arrows should be like the following ones:

[image: Arrow]

[image: Arrow]

I suppose that I can create an algorithm that decides the absolute X and Y coordinates of the "Start" and "End" points, more other few points (P0, P1, P2, etc.), that describes the curves. For example:

[image: Points of lines]

[image: Points of lines]

My problem is that I don't know how to do it. Usually I don't need low-level drawing in a Codename One app like in this case. Could you please show me a correct and complete code to do this drawing *(assuming to know the coordinates of Start, End, P0, P1, etc.)*? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit hard to do by hand. I would suggest using SVG to draw an arrow like this by using a tool such as Sketch or a similar vector graphics tool. Then using flamingo to convert it to an image: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/flamingo-svg-transcoder.html

Alternatively you can handcode it with a `GeneralPath` e.g.:

```
GeneralPath gp = new GeneralPath();

// move to start of path
gp.move(x, y);

// draw the curve of the arrow, we use a control point around which
// the curve is drawn and curve to the destination of the line
gp.curveTo(contolX, controlY, destX, destY);

// Stroke defines how the shape is drawn it accepts the line width
// cap style, join style and miter limit
Stroke st = new Stroke(2, Stroke.CAP_SQUARE, Stroke.JOIN_MITER, 1);

// red
graphics.setColor(0xff00000);

// now we can draw the shape
graphics.drawShape(gp, st);
```